# Need to wrap every useMemo dependency in a useCallback

Tags: reactjs, usecallback, react-usememo

I hope someone can help me. I tried to find the answer to my question but I couldn't, so if it is there and I couldn't find it, I apologize in advance.

So, I have an expensive operation that depends on 3 objects stored in the redux store. Since it is expensive, I want to execute it only when any of those 3 objects change.

To avoid making the function executed by useMemo too complex I split it in smaller functions that are then call when needed, something like this:

```
const computedValue = useMemo(() => {
  ...
  const result = processStoreObject1(storeObject1)
  ...
}, [storeObject1, storeObject2, storeObject3, processStoreObject1])
```

Now, I do not want to list processStoreObject1 as a dependency of useMemo, the computed value does not depend on it, the computed value only depend on the 3 store object. However, if I do not list the function as a dependency of useMemo I get this lint warning:

"React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'processStoreObject1'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)"

Because of this warning I have to include the function in the dependencies array, and because the function is declared inside the component, similar to this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  ...
  const processStoreObject1 = () => {
    // Do something
  }
  ...
}
```

I have to wrap it in a useCallback, otherwise it changes with each render and the useMemo is recalculated all the time (which is wrong). The warning that I get if I do not wrap the processStoreObject1 with useCallback is this:

"The 'processStoreObject1' function makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line NNN) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'processStoreObject1' definition into its own useCallback() Hook.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)"

I know one easy solution is to define processStoreObject1 outside the component so it does not get created in each render but I do not like that way, the function is only consumed inside the component so I want to have the definition in there.

To summarize, the question is, how can I use a function inside the function executed by useMemo without adding the dependency to the dependencies array. I know it is doable, I saw some examples of functions being used without being in the dependencies array.

I will be thankful if anyone can help me.

Thanks !

Comment: The `useCallback` approach is just fine for this situation. Is there a reason you don't want to use it? *I saw some examples of functions being used without being in the dependencies array.* Probably by those who didn't have enforced linting rules

Comment: Hi, and thanks ! I do not want the useCallback because it is not needed. I won't have any performance issue up to my knowledge generated for the functions being created in each render, I will have performance issues if they get executed each time (they are expensive) and that will only happen when the objects in the store change. So I will be memorizing functions (which has its own cost) when that is not a problem.

Comment: And regarding the functions that I am not requested to be added in the dependencies array. They were part of the same project, with the same linting rules. Sorry I forgot to mention that.